# Uniqueness of generator of Principal ideal domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

Just this simple question, I don't know why I am stuck:

Is the generator of a Principal ideal domain unique?

Comment: The  answer is no. It is unique only  up to a unit factor (in $\mathbf Z$, both $2$ and $-2$ generate the ideal of even numbers).

Comment: you mean a generator of an ideal in a PID?

Comment: Hint: $\ (a) = (b)\iff (a)\supseteq (b)\supseteq (a)\iff a\mid b\mid a\iff a,b\,$ are associate, by contains = divides for prinicpal ideals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The generator of a principal ideal is unique up to multiplication with a unit from your ring.